# My Cssed Button in html table is not getting styled correctly php

Tags: php, html, css, button

idk what's wrong in my script . the button should be styled with the css but all i get is this  https://ibb.co/cuwixy

the css

```
 .button {
background-color: #008CBA; /* Blue */
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.button5 {border-radius: 50%;}
```

the button scripted in html table in a php echo

```
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<td><form class='button button5'><input type='button' name='buy' value='buy'/></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're putting the class on the form, not the button

try:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<td><form><input type='button' name='buy' value='buy' class='button button5'/></form></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked . Another question if you don't mind , how can i size it ? as it seems very big

Comment: use `width` and `height`

Comment: any suggestions of values for width and height for a perfect vision ?

Comment: that's outside of the scope here. I don't know anything about what your'e building, why, other css you have, frameworks you're using, etc.. sorry